# Symfony 5.3 Mailer setup env vars not reading correctly

Tags: symfony, symfony5, phpdotenv, symfony-mailer

In a Symfony 5.3 project I am using the Mailer (..\Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface) to send mails.
For devolopment I required "symfony/google-mailer" with composer and set it up in .env.local.
Say username is "example@gmail.com" and password is "0000".

In .env.local I specified

```
MAILER_USER='example@gmail.com'
MAILER_PASSWORD='0000'

MAILER_DSN=gmail://MAILER_USER:MAILER_PASSWORD@default
```

which results in error

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "MAILER_USER" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "PLAIN", "XOAUTH2". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException: Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

As stated in the docs I changed the one special character in user name ("@") to it's URL-encoded form like

```
MAILER_USER='example%40gmail.com'
```

which then results in the error

```
Email "example%40gmail.com" does not comply with addr-spec of RFC 2822.
```

(Obviously the URL-encoding didn't work like expected (because it wasn't reversed?))
I tried to load the env vars in paramaters in services.yaml and use the parameters instead - but that lead to the first error too.

If I write the auth infos into the MAILER_DSN env var directly it just works fine without problems, like

```
MAILER_DSN=gmail://example@gmail.com:0000@default
```

So this seems to be a syntax problem which I can't figure out from the docs.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the single quotes and you need to wrap the env variables used in other env variables with `${}` [`sic`](https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/configuration.html#env-file-syntax)

```
MAILER_USER=example@gmail.com
MAILER_PASSWORD=0000

MAILER_DSN=gmail://${MAILER_USER}:${MAILER_PASSWORD}@default
```

Result:

```
$_SERVER['MAILER_DSN'] = "gmail://example@gmail.com:0000@default"
```

Comment: Thank you - that was exactly what I was missing. Didn't recognize this syntax... :-)

Answer (score 0):

.env :

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://username:password@smtp.gmail.com
```

You have to enable access to applications in google parameters (security).

Comment: You are talking about the less secure apps setting to turn on right? I did that allready. Changing to the syntax you provided doesn't change anything. Same error...